# Can a sequence of series converge to 0 if all the terms in each of the sequences are atrictly positive?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, measure-theory

Maybe the question seems a little strange so I will provide a bit of context before. I'm trying to prove the following:

Let $μ$ be a $σ$-finite measure on the measurable space ($\mathbb{R}$, $B$) , where $B$ denotes the Borel $σ$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $E$ $=$ {$x ∈ R : μ({x}) > 0$} is countable.

If we assume for a contradiction the set is uncountable, there must be at least one set $C$ with finite measure with uncountably many singletons with positive measure. We can then take a sequence of disjoint sets contained in $C$, each of them being a countable union of singletons with positive measure. Then we have that $C$'s measure is greater or equal than the infinite sum of the measures of this sequence, which is equal to the infinte sum of the infinite sum of the measure of a sequence of singletons with strictly positive measure. If it's possible to show that this series is divergent, we would find a contradiction with $C$'s measure being finite and we'd be done.

I know there's an easier way to prove this statement, but my intuition tells me that this infinite sum of an infinite sum where all the terms of each respective sequence are strictly positive cannot converge, particularly because a sequence of series whose respective sequences are strictly positive doesn't seem to be able to converge to 0. Is this true? And if so, how do I prove it?

Comment: For each natural $n$, choose your favorite strictly positive series which converges to $2^{-n}$ (a geometric series, for example).  You can't sum positive things to zero, but you can use this procedure to construct a "series of series" to converge to any positive thing you like.

Comment: @XanderHenderson maybe I'm missunderstanding, but if each of my series converges to 2^n, the series of series is clearly not going to converge, as not even the sequence of series is convergent

Comment: @Fernando For each $n$, choose your favorite series which sums to $1/2^n$.  What is $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}?$$
(Ah... there was a typo in the original comment---fixed.)

Comment: @XanderHenderson got it, thanks :)